# How to return a pointer from a function that calls a function by pointer to a function that returns a pointer?

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
node *insertPlaceOrder(node *head, char *firstName, char *lastName, int day, int month, 
    int year, char *birthPlace) {
  //CODE
return head;                     
}

node *insertToList(node (*(*order))(node*, char*, char*, int, int, int, char*), node *head, 
    char *firstName, char *lastName, int day, int month, int year, char *birthPlace) {
  return (*order)(head, firstName, lastName, day, month, year, birthPlace);
}
```

When I debug this code, the compiler gives me the following error:

> incompatible types when returning type 'node {aka struct node}' but 'node * {aka struct node *}' was expected.

How can I get the `insertToList()` function to return the pointer to a struct node that the function `insertPlaceOrder()` returns?

Comment: Now is a good time to learn about *type-aliases* using [`typedef`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef). Use type-aliases of the function types, and it will all become *much* simpler.

Comment: Perhaps `node (*(*order))(node* ...` --> `node *(*order)(node*....`?  Posting your `node` definition would add some clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra set of parenthesis in the function pointer type.  You have:

```
node (*(*order))(node*, char*, char*, int, int, int, char*)
```

Which defines `order` to be a pointer-to-pointer-to-function returning a `node`, not a pointer-to-function returning a `node *`.  It should instead be:

```
node *(*order)(node*, char*, char*, int, int, int, char*)
```

Comment: I thought so as well but the code as you proposed it gives me an error: conflicting types for 'insertToList'

Comment: @RealSlimShady Then you need to change the function's prototype to match the definition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it finally works now. :D

Comment: @RealSlimShady Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.